# i have 108gb worth of space left but it says i can only use 180mb of it

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-usage

ok, so last week i got ubuntu and my friend set it up for me and when i installed steam i got a message saying "you have 180mb worth of space left"

after that i was completely triggered and decided to seek help.
i found out later that i could increase my partions with 108gb left,which sounds to me like my friend only gave me 1gb out of the 109 he could've

my computer specs:

- used to have windows 7
- thinkpad model t410
- intel core v5
- lenovo.

things i have tried:
everything google has to offer (no freaking joke i literally spent 3 hours google-ing), i tried increasing partions at random but nothing happened. and thats about it

i saw some random tutorials to solve something like this but none of them used my ubuntu version (16.04)

edit:df -h results

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           375M  6.2M  369M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        46G   44G  125M 100% /
tmpfs           1.9G  324K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           375M   48K  375M   1% /run/user/1001
```

edit: results of lsblk -fo +size

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT   SIZE
sda                                                                 149.1G
├─sda1 ext4         5d570f21-9c9d-41a5-b7a3-00e4e0fac483 /           46.6G
└─sda3 swap         b1485ea3-bfda-467a-9da7-8e48c4cb5890 [SWAP]       1.9G
sr0                                                                     2K
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the outputs of the terminal commands `df -h` and `lsblk -fo +size`.

Comment: ok hold on a second

Comment: Can't read your output. Indent, prevent line breaks. This one "i/dev/sda1 46G 44G 125M 100% /" seems to say your root partition is 100% full at 45G, I suspect you thought you were asking for more than you got.

Comment: i'm extremely new to this,i have no idea what that means so can someone please walk me through what i need to do in order to fix this

Comment: Your Ubuntu partition is only 47 GB big and completely full, but the disk has 150 GB. That means you can grow it by about 100GB. Please add the output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print` so that we can see how exactly the partitions are currently positioned. Then I can tell you what to move how using GParted.